# Slack flickering and Rendering issue

Tags: slack

We have graphical glitches on slack client on our Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS like screen flickering and rendering issues. We have tried to disable acceleration and to resize slack window but it does not work on the slack client.

Answer (score 0):

*First and foremost, It would be great if you can provide the details of your hardware.*

If you have used snap package to install slack then trying .deb package available on [slack website](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/downloads/linux) might help.

In case you already have .deb slack package installed then I don't think switching to snap would help. I would be able to help further only after knowing the specs of your computer.